# ReactJS - access this.props within a promise

Tags: javascript, reactjs, promise

I have a static method which returns a promise:

```
static getInfo(ID)
 { return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {   
    api.getList(ID)
      .then((List) => {
        resolve(Info);
      })
      .catch((error) => {
        // here I need to access this.props which is undefined
        console.log(this.props);

      });
     .catch(reject);
   });
 }
```

this.props is `undefined` within the promise. how can I access it?

Comment: You are trying to access `this` in a static method.

Comment: this would be scoped to the promise and not the this.props try var self = this before calling the method

Comment: @FadiAboMsalam: No, the functions above are arrow functions. (And `this` != "scope")

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23803743/what-is-the-explicit-promise-construction-antipattern-and-how-do-i-avoid-it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As mentioned in a comment on the question, you are using `this` inside a static method which by definition is not associated with an instance (and hence, `this` wont be pointing to a component instance).

You can either:

1. Make it an instance method by removing `static`
2. OR, Pass the props/component instance as an argument to the method.

   `static getInfo(ID,props){...}`

   `Component.getInfo(ID, this.props) //In your component where this.props is available`